# Why does JSON OVERLAPS MYSQL function isn't working?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to use the JSON_OVERLAPS sql function to compare arrays
When i do :

```
SELECT * 
FROM publications 
WHERE JSON_OVERLAPS(descrip, '[["airplane"], ["projectile"], ["horse"]]') IS NOT NULL
```

It gives me this error:

> FUNCTION user.JSON_OVERLAPS does not exist

I use mySQL 8.0.18

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you certain you are using MySQL 8.0.18? Please run `select version();` to verify.

Comment: yes i'm using mysql 8.0.18 on wampserver 3.2.0 64bit and using phpmyadmin 4.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for this stupid question. It finds out that i was running on a mariadb server on phpmyadmin so i thin it's resolved

Comment: Coming soon in MariaDB 10.9!